# HScrollBar Control in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, scroll, scrollbar

I was wondering, do you guys know about some replication of the HScrollBar from WinForms to ASP.Net?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "control" in ASP.NET equivalent to HScrollBar.  Although you can use features of HTML to get a similar result.

If you are after a scrollable box on your ASP.NET form your might want to try a fixed hight DIV with overflow: scroll turned on e.g;

```
<div style="overflow: scroll; height: 50px">
The quick brown fox...<br />
The quick brown fox...<br />
The quick brown fox...<br />
The quick brown fox...<br />
The quick brown fox...<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent control in pure asp.net but the css properties or the style property of div tags can be used for th purpose.